# Facebook open graph og:image pulling up altered/broken image

Tags: facebook, image, image-processing, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to set the facebook image if people share my website and it seems like simple setup. I added the following:

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
  <meta content="http://graph.facebook.com/MusicFestivalNation/picture" property="og:image">
```

I have tried using the asset pipeline, which is connected to s3 and got the same result. The image is "succesfully" loaded as you can see the impression of it but it is barely visible and  is almost a sketch of the image.

Here's the image I'm loading,

[image]

And here's what it looks like when it is loaded

[image]

As you can see it is pulling the image but there is just a really faint sketch of the image instead of the colored photo. I have made sure that I used http because I saw there was a glitch with http. I figure it would work fine since I am literally using facebooks graph api for the image. Anyone have an idea of what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. The s3 images were failing due to the https issue with og:image and the default facebook image is 50x50, which is too small. I just had to increase the width and height of the graph url.

```
<meta content="http://graph.facebook.com/MusicFestivalNation/picture?width=800&height=800" property="og:image">
```